# Why force generic parameter to implement an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, implements

I'm working with WebAPI, my API needs to call an external API to get data back for processing.

I designed a `BaseResponse` class as below:

```cs
public interface IResponseData
{
}

public class BaseResponse<T> where T : IResponseData
{
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public T? Data { get; set; }
}
```

Since `Data` must be some kind of response data, the T parameter must implement `IResponseData`.

But then I realize I can just do this instead and get rid of the entire generic part.

```cs
public interface IResponseData
{
}

public class BaseResponse
{
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public IResponseData? Data { get; set; }
}
```

What is the point of using `where T : IResponseData` here? Are there any cases the first example is better than the second one, and vice versa?

For more context (this is quite long text), currently, I have 2 types of response, `SingleResponse` and `MultipleResponse`, both of which implement `IResponseData`.

I was trying to do this:

```
BaseResponse<IResponseData> baseResponse = new BaseResponse<SingleResponse>();
```

And I get an error saying that I can not convert `SingleResponse` to `IResponseData`, despite the fact that `SingleResponse` implements `IResponseData`.

I did some research about covariant, but still don't understand how to make the code above work. Can someone show me how to make this work? (more detail context info below.)

The reason why I write the code above is because:

1. I have a method that processes response based on the input parameter count. If count is 1, `SingleRequest` and `SingleResponse`, if count > 1, `MultipleRequest` and `MultipleResponse`.
2. I have to prepare a request, call API, validate response, and process response data for either case.
3. Request classes don't have anything in common. Only responses have, which is why I create base class `BaseResponse`.

So before, you can imaging the code to be like this:

```cs
if (input.Count == 1)
{
  SingleRequest singleRequest = new SingleRequest();
  BaseResponse<SingleResponse> singleResponse = await getSingleAPI();
  Validate(singleResponse);
  Process(singleResponse);
} 
else if (input.Count > 1)
{
  MultipleRequest multipleRequest = new MultipleRequest();
  BaseResponse<MultipleResponse> multipleResponse = await getMultipleAPI();
  Validate(multipleResponse);
  Process(multipleResponse);
}
```

As you can see, only the request is different. The follow-up process is the same for both cases. I don't want code duplication. So, I want to create a `BaseResponse<T>` with T implements `IResponseData`.

Now, I can do this outside the if else

```cs
BaseResponse<MultipleResponse> response;
if (input.Count == 1)
{
  SingleRequest singleRequest = new SingleRequest();
  response = await getSingleAPI();
} 
else if (input.Count > 1)
{
  MultipleRequest multipleRequest = new MultipleRequest();
  response = await getMultipleAPI();
}

Validate(response)
Process(response)
```

But `response = await getSingleAPI();` and `response = await getMultipleAPI();` will not compile since `getSingleAPI()` returns `BaseResponse<SingleResponse>()` and getMultipleAPI() returns `BaseResponse<MultipleResponse>()`.

They produce the same error as `BaseResponse<IResponseData> baseResponse = new BaseResponse<SingleResponse>();`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It depends. I think the answer may lie on how you actually intend to consume these objects. What do you do with the `baseResponse` object after you get it? Do you care about the type (single/multi)? Will you treat it differently based on it and how do make that determination?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is "opinion-based" given that one can provide concrete non-opinionated code examples showing why some code would require the interface type constraint `where T : IResponseData`

Comment: @MatthewWatson answers clearly demonstrate that the question is opinion-based - just random reasoning why generics are useful. None of the reason actually apply to OP's case because their use-case does not require generics at all...

Comment: Is my question too broad? Should I create a new question?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one reason: Code using your `BaseResponse` might want to use a class that implements `IResponseData` which contains items that are not part of `IResponseData`.

For example, given:

```
public class BaseResponse<T> where T : IResponseData
{
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public T?  Data       { get; set; }
}

public interface IResponseData
{
}

public sealed class MyResponseData: IResponseData
{
    public int ImportantMethod() => 42;
}
```

You might have code like this:

```
var baseResponse = new BaseResponse<MyResponseData>
{
    Data = new MyResponseData()
};

MyResponseData result = baseResponse.Data;

Console.WriteLine(result.ImportantMethod());
```

But if you change the `BaseResponse` class definition to

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public int            ResponseId { get; set; }
    public IResponseData? Data       { get; set; }
}
```

then the code will no longer compile.

---

If you can limit the usage of the type parameter to just the return type of items in the interface (rather than argument types for items in the interface) then you can allow some conversions by using [the `out` keyword (generic modifier)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier).

An example will make this clearer:

You would invent a new `IBaseResponse<T>` interface, and declare its type parameter as `out` like so:

```
public interface IBaseResponse<out T> where T: class, IResponseData
{
    int ResponseId { get; set; }
    T? Data { get; }
}
```

Note that this interface does *not* have a setter for `Data`. If it did, the code would not compile because you're not allowed to use an `out` generic type as an input.

Anyway, after creating that interface your class can implement it like so:

```
public class BaseResponse<T> : IBaseResponse<T> where T: class, IResponseData
{
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public T?  Data       { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming the previous definition of `MyResponseData`, now the following code will compile OK:

```
var baseResponse = new BaseResponse<MyResponseData>
{
    Data = new MyResponseData()
};

IBaseResponse<IResponseData> test = baseResponse;
IResponseData? data = test.Data;
```

It's not quite what you want, because `IBaseResponse<IResponseData>.Data` does not have a setter, of course.

Answer (score 1):

One reason is performance. A method with a generic constraint will be specialized for each type. This can be relevant for things like generic math, consider:

```
public T Add(T a, T b) where T : INumber<T>{
    return a + b
}
```

If this is called once with `double` and once with `decimal` the compiler will generate two version of the method, each fully optimized for the specific type. A non generic `Add`-method would cause the parameters to be boxed, as well as virtual calls to get the correct add method. This overhead can become significant for math heavy code.

That said, there are absolutely cases where generic constraints are overused, and a non generic variant would be better.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're asking three questions:

1. Why `BaseResponse<IResponseData> baseResponse = new BaseResponse<SingleResponse>();` is not working
2. How to make it work
3. When and where to use genereics.

Here are the answers:

1. Because `BaseResponse<IResponseData>` could not guarantee that your object which is `BaseResponse<SingleResponse>()` will set `SingleResponse` in `Data` property.
2. To make it work you should remove setter of the property. But you could use it in implementation.

```
Ex.:

interface IData {}

class Data : IData {}

interface IDataHolder<out T> where T : IData
{
    T Data { get; }
}

class DataHolder<T> : IDataHolder<T>
    where T : IData
{
    T Data { get; set; }
}

// Then this will work
IDataHolder<IData> dataHolder = new DataHolder<Data>();
```

3. To use some class specific methods\properties\etc. For example you have interface `ICar` with method `void Drive()` and implementation `Truck : ICar` also have method `UnhookTrailer()`. To get access to `UnhookTrailer()` method you need to cast or hold an object with exactly this type. `Warehouse` working only with `Truck` should implement methods only for this class but not for all the `ICar`

Answer (score -1):

In general.

One way I use "Generics Constraints".. it is more of the "high level variety".

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Below is a quote from the article, it is NOT formatting well, so go to the URL above instead.  But I will leave the quote below in case the URL dies in the future.

> Constraint    Description
>
> where T : struct  The type argument must be a non-nullable value type.
> For information about nullable value types, see Nullable value types.
> Because all value types have an accessible parameterless constructor,
> the struct constraint implies the new() constraint and can't be
> combined with the new() constraint. You can't combine the struct
> constraint with the unmanaged constraint.
>
> where T : class   The type argument must be a reference type. This
> constraint applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array
> type. In a nullable context, T must be a non-nullable reference type.
>
> where T : class?  The type argument must be a reference type, either
> nullable or non-nullable. This constraint applies also to any class,
> interface, delegate, or array type.
>
> where T : notnull The type argument must be a non-nullable type. The
> argument can be a non-nullable reference type or a non-nullable value
> type.
>
> where T : default This constraint resolves the ambiguity when you need
> to specify an unconstrained type parameter when you override a method
> or provide an explicit interface implementation. The default
> constraint implies the base method without either the class or struct
> constraint. For more information, see the default constraint spec
> proposal.
>
> where T : unmanaged   The type argument must be a non-nullable unmanaged
> type. The unmanaged constraint implies the struct constraint and can't
> be combined with either the struct or new() constraints.
>
> where T : new()   The type argument must have a public parameterless
> constructor. When used together with other constraints, the new()
> constraint must be specified last. The new() constraint can't be
> combined with the struct and unmanaged constraints.
>
> where T : < base class name > The type argument must be or derive from
> the specified base class. In a nullable context, T must be a
> non-nullable reference type derived from the specified base class.
>
> where T : < base class name >?    The type argument must be or derive
> from the specified base class. In a nullable context, T may be either
> a nullable or non-nullable type derived from the specified base class.
>
> where T : < interface name >  The type argument must be or implement
> the specified interface. Multiple interface constraints can be
> specified. The constraining interface can also be generic. In a
> nullable context, T must be a non-nullable type that implements the
> specified interface.
>
> where T : < interface name >? The type argument must be or implement
> the specified interface. Multiple interface constraints can be
> specified. The constraining interface can also be generic. In a
> nullable context, T may be a nullable reference type, a non-nullable
> reference type, or a value type. T may not be a nullable value type.
>
> where T : U   The type argument supplied for T must be or derive from
> the argument supplied for U. In a nullable context, if U is a
> non-nullable reference type, T must be non-nullable reference type. If
> U is a nullable reference type, T may be either nullable or
> non-nullable.

In your case, you have a "very specific constraint", and so you are correct, that may be overkill.

and I would prefer your next option of

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public IResponseData? Data { get; set; }
}
```

But to your question....there are "more interesting" choices for generics constraints" than a single ISomething.

Also (as per the article). you can have multiple constraints:

```
class EmployeeList<T> where T : Employee, IEmployee, System.IComparable<T>, new()
{
    // ...
}
```

...

Most recently, I have created a generic constraint on an Enum.

```
public class PageResponse<T, E> where E : Enum
{
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
    
    public E OrderByEnum { get; set; }
}
```

Here I am capturing the results of a "single page of paging" (as in a REST service).

Most of the properties are "for any page request" (the ints above), BUT .. the other things are more fluid.

The "Items" (the "T" above) could be any POCO object.
Imagine "Department" in one case and "Employee" in another.

And the "OrderByEnum" could be different.

```
public Enum DepartmentSortBy
{
  DepartmentNameAsc,
  DepartmentNameDesc,
  DepartmentCreateDateAsc,
  DepartmentCreateDateDesc
}


public Enum EmployeeSortBy
{
  LastNameAsc,
  LastNameDesc,
  HireDateAsc,
  HireDateDesc
}
```

so I want to keep the "order by" enum "generic".. so it can be reused.

so I can do the two below things:

```
PageResponse<Department, DepartmentSortBy> pr = new PageResponse<Department, DepartmentSortBy>();
```

and

```
PageResponse<Employee, EmployeeSortBy> pr = new PageResponse<Employee, EmployeeSortBy>();
```

but I cannot do

```
PageResponse<Employee, ArithmeticException> bogus = new PageResponse<Employee, ArithmeticException>();
```

because ArithmeticException is not an Enum.